# Switching from 8.1 pro to 8.1 single language?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I bought a new laptop which came with 8.1 single language. I tried to upgrade it using my old key for 8.1 pro. Sadly, my old key is now out of activation. So, I have to go back to 8.1 single language.

Since the current version is pro, I am unable to use the key that came with the system. It simply says "this key won't work on pro version". And also, because of this, bios update doesn't work.

So, I have to go back to the old version, the one that came with the laptop. How do I do that, without reinstalling everything?

Comment: You won't be able to do this without installation Windows 8.1 again.  Windows has no mechanic to downgrade from Professional to Single Language it only has a mechanic to upgrade Single Language to Professional w/MC.  Before you do that attempt a phone activation on the license your trying to use.

Comment: i tried phone activation. ms says they can't help with it. i got the bios key back using produkey. but, i can't seem to use it.

Comment: if i download the single language version, then use it to refresh the pc, will it save all my settings? or will it revert to original state?

Comment: You won't be able to use the `Windows 8.1` SL key to activate a Professional edition of `Windows 8.1` that is to be expected.  If you cannot activate the `Windows 8.1 Professional` license because its already been activated and not eligible to be moved then your only recourse is to reinstall Windows and lose your settings.

Comment: hmm. so, reset the pc won't work either? i don't want to lose all the games and everything else i installed.

Comment: You would need to purchase another `Windows 8.1 Professional` license in that case.